# IP spoofing not used for attacking - wording?

Tags: ip, terminology

I would like to express that I do IP spoofing, but do not use it for an attack. Since IP spoofing seems to be always used in combination with performing an attack, I wonder if there is a word with the same meaning, but without the negative

Comment: I think what I was looking for is IP masquerading. any objections?

Comment: IP masquerading is specifically another name for NAT and would be misunderstood as such. IP spoofing is IP spoofing, whether used in an attack or not, although I can't think of many legitimate uses for it. Could you provide more context?

Comment: this article says (in the very beginning), that spoofing is the same as masquerading: http://all.net/CID/Attack/papers/Masquerading.html

Comment: Rather than using a single article written by a student (of unknown background) and possibly quite old (most recent reference seems to be 2002) to back the position you want to convince others of, why don't you use your search engine of choice to query the term "IP masquerading" and see what results?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: no answer helped me. I cannot provide my own answer. and I cannot delete the question. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Spoofing is sourcing traffic with an address that you aren't. Masquerading is *changing* the source to an address that you represent. (i.e. NAT)

Spoofing is *highly* discouraged, and often out-right denied by network security constraints. *HOWEVER*, there are load balancing systems that use an asymmetric process whereby the answering server directly answers requests forwarded from the load balancing device. (browser sends to LB address, LB forwards to actual server, actual server replies with the LB's address directly to the internet bypassing the LB. This means the LB doesn't have to process as much traffic.) I seem to recall this being called *Global Mode* load balancing.